# Selenium script - ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, http-post

Running the selenium script bellow, I get the following errors : `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused` and `urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f872820b490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused`. The script worked fine and then suddenly this started to happen. Does this have something to do with repetitive requests?

**My code**

```
url = "https://browzine.com/libraries/1374/subjects"

driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

subj_list_xpath = "//span[@class='subjects-list-subject-name']"
subjects_avail = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, subj_list_xpath)
journal_list_xpath = journals_list_xpath = "//div[@class='image-container']"
journal_avail = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, journal_list_xpath)
years_list_xpath = "//div[@class='year  tabindex' or @class='year selected tabindex']"
years_avail = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, years_list_xpath)

amount_articles = 0
amount_jour = 0

for i in range(len(subjects_avail)):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, subj_list_xpath)))
    subjects_avail = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, subj_list_xpath)
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(subjects_avail[i]).click(subjects_avail[i]).perform()
    for j in range(len(journal_avail)):
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, journal_list_xpath)))
        journal_avail = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, journal_list_xpath)
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(journal_avail[j]).click(journal_avail[j]).perform()
        amount_jour = amount_jour + 1
        print(amount_jour)
        for y in range(len(years_avail)):
            WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, years_list_xpath)))
            years_avail = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, years_list_xpath)
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(years_avail[y]).click(years_avail[y]).perform()
```

Comment: could be connection between the webdriver and the browser... does the browser open?  and/or does it close shortly after opening?  Is so, you may have a webdriver/browser version mismatch.

Comment: @pcalkins the browser does open, it does take a while to locate the first element though. It used to locate it instantly. Now it waits a while, finds the first element and performs the click and then I get this error right after.

Comment: hmm... well you are messing with the iterator there... I would avoid re-assigning subjects_avail in the loop that's using it's length as the range.  (same with journal_avail) Seems like you'd also be throwing a lot of stale element exceptions depending on what that click does...  doesn't really explain your connection error, though.

Comment: @pcalkins yeah the loop makes it feel a bit fishy but I don't really have an alternative in mind. And as far as I can see there's no obvious mistake with the code... not sure if i'm missing something though